# Lazy loading iPhone images

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview, lazy-loading

If I would like to have lazy loading like **google+** or **facebook** app (maybe even 9gag), should I go with `UITableView` or `UIScrollView`?

The goal is to load whole new set of cells or `scrollview` pages (not just thumbnail like apple `lazyloading` `tableview`). If you have facebook app, try scrolling down fast and you will see what I mean.

Any example would be also helpful.

Thanks.

Comment: I think what the guy wants is infinite scrolling rather than loading async images http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=infinite+scrolling+%5Bobjective-c%5D

Answer (score 1):

You should prefer table view for this. with tableview , You can use reusable customcell. tableview can be useful for Auto layout in landscape mode and if app is universal the tableview is more useful.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this: `https://github.com/nicklockwood/AsyncImageView`. This is a best example for loading images asynchronously. The library can also be used to load and cache images independently of a UIImageView as it provides direct access to the underlying loading and caching classes.

Answer (score 1):

Using Grand Central Dispatch you can do this.

The following link might be useful.

http://www.raywenderlich.com/4295/multithreading-and-grand-central-dispatch-on-ios-for-beginners-tutorial

Answer (score 0):

I would use a uicollection view. Here is an example that uses uitableview, but you can take it and modify it a bit to work with a collection view.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/LazyTableImages/Introduction/Intro.html

If you would like to use a third party library, I would suggest looking at [**AFNetworking**](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) It's one of the most highly used and has a very easy to use function that extends UIImageView [**LINK**](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking#image-request)

Also as an FYI, a scrollview is part of a tableview.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage), really easy to use, it support caching and asynchronous loading.

Comment: In Xcode, default is iOS device, and if i change to iPhone, it just compiles but doesn't start the simulator ??